# django projects(saleor) python manage.py migrate error message

Tags: python, django, saleor

**Hello Guys I tried to migrate using the command python manage.py migrate
and I got this error**
**am done with the set of my environment and I also cloned the saleor reporsitory on github but am still getting these errors.
what can I do to fix it?**

```
C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\saleor\saleor\urls.py:35: UserWarning: The debug 
toolbar was not installed. Ignore
the error.             settings.py should already have warned the user about it.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\saleor\saleor\plugins\checks.py", line 20, 
in check_plugins
    check_single_plugin(plugin_path, errors)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\saleor\saleor\plugins\checks.py", line 43, 
in check_single_plugin
    plugin_class = import_string(plugin_path)
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "c:\users\timothy dawadakpoye\appdata\local\programs\python\python38- 
32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Timothy 
Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\saleor\saleor\plugins\invoicing\plugin.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .utils import generate_invoice_number, generate_invoice_pdf
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\saleor\saleor\plugins\invoicing\utils.py", 
line 8, in <module>
    from weasyprint import HTML
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\weasyprint\__init__.py", line 440, in <module>
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\weasyprint\css\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import computed_values, media_queries
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
 packages\weasyprint\css\computed_values.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
 packages\weasyprint\text.py", line 14, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
 packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    cairo = dlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Timothy Dawadakpoye\Desktop\pyprojs\apron\denv\lib\site- 
packages\cairocffi\__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\GTK2-Runtime Win64\bin\libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
cannot load library 'libcairo.so': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': error 0x7e
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': error 0xc1
```

**How do I fix it? am using the saleor project
am working on an e commerce site with the saleor framework and django together**

Comment: share your saleor urls.py

Comment: `OSError: no library called "cairo" was found`. As error says, this cairo lib is missing,  you need to install if from here https://www.cairographics.org/download/

Comment: I just finished downloading this Glade/Gtk+ for Windows